# MS Graph SDK - assigning license to any user

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to use the assignLicense functionality in the MS Graph API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)

As I'm using the SDK, I'm looking at the C# sample, which uses

```
graphServiceClient.Me.AssignLicense
```

But, graphServiceClient.Me refers to the logged in user.. I'm in a server side app, so .Me is the app, not a user, and I don't see a way to specify the Id/UserPrincipalName to send the request to the the proper user.

Any ideas on how to inject the proper id/upn when using the GraphServiceClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Me` with Application scopes (i.e. an app-only scenario). "Me" is simply an alias for the currently authenticated user and since you have no authenticated user, Graph has no way of knowing which user you want to address.

You need to explicitly specify the user, either by `id` or their `userPrincipalName`:

```
await graphClient
  .Users["id"]
  .AssignLicense(licensesToAdd, licensesToRemove) 
  .Request()      
  .PostAsync();

await graphClient
  .Users["upn@domain.onmicrosoft.com"]
  .AssignLicense(licensesToAdd, licensesToRemove) 
  .Request()      
  .PostAsync();
```

*Note that `licensesToAdd` is a `List<AssignedLicense>` while `licensesToRemove` is a `List<Guid>`*

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out on my own

```
graphServiceClient.Users[id].AssignLicense
```

is the way to go.. not sure how to do it with the upn, but the User's ID works fine.

Comment: and it seems the upn can be used instead of the user's ID as well :)